# How to use key-words instead of URL's in youtube-dl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, youtube-dl

I am writing a bot for my discord server and I've put a `play` command to my bot. It works fine with URL's but I want the bot to work with searchs too. So instead of copying and pasting the URL I want to be able to write the keyword for it. This is the `play` command:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    def check_queue():
        Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
        if Queue_infile is True:
            DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
            length = len(os.listdir(DIR))
            still_q = length - 1
            try:
                first_file = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
            except:
                print("No more queued song(s)\n")
                queues.clear()
                return
            main_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            song_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + "\\" + first_file)
            if length != 0:
                print("Song done, playing next queued\n")
                print(f"Songs still in queue: {still_q}")
                song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
                if song_there:
                    os.remove("song.mp3")
                shutil.move(song_path, main_location)
                for file in os.listdir("./"):
                    if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                        os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')

                voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
                voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
                voice.source.volume = 0.07

            else:
                queues.clear()
                return

        else:
            queues.clear()
            print("No songs were queued before the ending of the last song\n")

    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            queues.clear()
            print("Removed old song file")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Trying to delete song file, but it's being played")
        await ctx.send("ERROR: Music playing")
        return

    Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
    try:
        Queue_folder = "./Queue"
        if Queue_infile is True:
            print("Removed old Queue Folder")
            shutil.rmtree(Queue_folder)
    except:
        print("No old Queue folder")

    await ctx.send("Getting everything ready now")

    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'quiet': True,
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    try:
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            print("Downloading audio now\n")
            ydl.download([url])
    except:
        print("FALLBACK: youtube-dl does not support this URL, using Spotify (This is normal if Spotify URL)")
        c_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        system("spotdl -f " + '"' + c_path + '"' + " -s " + url)

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.14

    nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
    await ctx.send(f"Playing: {nname[0]}")
    print("playing\n")
```

I know It looks a little complex, It's because It has a queue feature. I tried several solution I saw online, but they didn't help because of the differences between the code they gave and the code that I have. If there is any space mistakes, It's because I might have forgot to put spaces in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your youtube-dl options, set `default_search`. For example,

```
ydl_opts = {
    'default_search': 'ytsearch',
# ... all other options
```

will search using the YouTube search if the input is not a URL. This works with any of the [supported sites](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html), for example `'default_search': 'https://instagram.com/explore/tags/'` will search instagram tags by default.